# Django passing a model instance to slightly different model

Tags: python, django

I'm writing an django app for a project where everybody can change articles but the changes that users commit have to be viewed by someone before they go online. So you see it is a bit like the system used by wikipedia.

```
class Content(models.Model):
    tp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)

class ChangeSet(Content):
    content = models.ForeignKey('Content')
```

those are my models.
ChangeSet just inherits the Content and it has a ForeignKey to the original content.

my question is how do I save my ChangeSet?

```
def content(request, content_slug):
    content = get_object_or_404(Content, slug=content_slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_content = ContentModelForm(request.POST, instance=content)

        new_content = new_content.save(commit=False)

        changeset = ChangeSet(content=content)
```

can I somehow pass the ChangeSet the content instance?
Does Django recognize that those two models are the same except for the fk?
Or do I have to manually add every field like:

```
changeset.topic = new_content.topic
```

#### Edit #1

It doesn't look like it's a big deal to just write 'changeset.topic = new_content.topic' but I shortened my real Content model so you guys won't have to read all the stuff that is irrelevant for solving this problem.

#### Edit #2

To generalize the question a bit more.
What is the best way saving Changesets?
Making a new model for the changeset like I did or should I just add a ForeignKey with a reference to itself to my Content model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your models coded, I don't think it's going to work like you're expecting.  In this case ChangeSet inherits from Content.  The way Django implements this is by create a OneToOneField that connects ChangeSet with Content.  This means 2 things for your application:

1. Having the ForeignKey is pointless as that's like having an FK to yourself (and there's already a OneToOne behind the scenes anyways)
2. ChangeSet is always going to point to the most recent instance of Content.  There's nothing in this model setup that is going to save a copy of changes.

Probably the best method I've seen to achieve this (used by [django-reversion](http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/)) is to take Content, serialized it, then save the Content Id and Content Type to a model.  You can than access it like ChangeSet.original.{tp/topic/etc.}.

Have a look at it's model code here:  [models.py](http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/source/browse/trunk/src/reversion/models.py).  The equivalent to your ChangeSet would be the Version model.